# Referencing a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run through a list in column A and if it has a corresponding yes next to it in column B, create a new tab with the name in column A.

I know very basic VBA. I am not referencing the range correctly as I get my message box when some are true.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    lastcell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcellsecond = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For a = 2 To lastcellsecond
        If Cells(a, 2) = "Yes" Then
            For i = 2 To lastcell
                With ThisWorkbook
                    newname = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, 1).Value
                   .Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
                   ActiveSheet.Name = newname         
                End With
            Next i
        Else
            MsgBox "RETRY"
        End If
    Next a

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You have two loops but only need one. Also, you should specify which worksheet the `Cells` are on.

Answer (score 0):

Here are several ways to iterate over the ranges:

### Using Arrays

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim values As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet")
        values = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)).Resize(, 2).Value
    End With

    Dim r As Long
    Dim newname As String

    For r = 1 To UBound(values, 2)
        If values(r, 2) = "Yes" Then
            newname = values(r, 1)
            With ThisWorkbook
                .Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = newname
            End With
        End If
    Next

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

### For Each Loop

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim newname As String
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet")
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1))
            If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Yes" Then
                newname = cell.Value
                With ThisWorkbook
                    .Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = newname
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

### For Loop

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim newname As String
    Dim r As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet")
        For r = 2 To .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1))
            If .Cells(r, 2).Value = "Yes" Then
                newname = .Cells(r, 1).Value
                With ThisWorkbook
                    .Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = newname
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

I highly recommend you watch:

- [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)
- [Excel VBA Introduction Part 16 - For Next Loops](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=JyWrLH7monI&index=18&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)
- [Excel VBA Introduction Part 17 - For Each Loops](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=R2nlDu-2E4o&index=19&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)